# ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007faf65bb0e38 when trying to get checkbox values

Tags: html, sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

new to rails developer. 
I am building a simple rails app that allows users to add ebooks, store them in the database and then enables the user to view the ebooks.

I made a form consisting of multiple checkboxes that asks the user to check the genre of the ebooks that they are uploading. However, when I try to display the genre I get the following on an ActiveRecord_Association_CollectionProxy on my show.html.erb. How can I convert this so that the output will be a string of values of the checkboxes?

I've already tried to convert

```
    <h1>Genre(s)</h1>
    <%= @book.genres%>
```

to an array by adding a to_a at the end of @book.genres, however it returns an error:

```
    SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: genres.genres_id: SELECT 
     "genres".* FROM "genres" WHERE "genres"."genres_id" = ?
```

So I added a migration file

```
    class AddGenresToBook < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
      def change
       add_column :books, :genres, :string
      end
    end
```

However, is still the same. Also tried looping through with:

```
      <h1>Genre(s)</h1>
        <% @book.genres.each do |genre| %>
         <%= genre %>
       <%end%>
```

Still the same error. I know I am supposed to fiddle with the schema.db however at this point my knowledge isn't really deep enough. Please give me advice on what I can do further.

new.html.erb

```
         <div class="form-group">
  <h5>Genre(s) <span style="color:red">*</span></h5> <p class="error"><%= @book.errors.full_messages%></p>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids,{multiple: true}, "action", nil%> Action <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "adventure", nil%> Adventure <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "comedy", nil%> Comedy <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "drama", nil%> Drama <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "ecchi", nil%> Ecchi <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "fantasy", nil%> Fantasy <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "horror", nil%> Horror <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "magic", nil%> Magic <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "mystery", nil%> Mystery <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "psychological", nil%> Psychological <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "sciFi", nil%> Sci Fi <br> 
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "sliceofLife", nil%> Slice of Life <br>
    <%= f.check_box :genres_ids, {multiple: true}, "supernaural", nil%> Supernatural <br>
    <h6>Or Add a Custom Genre(s)</h6>
    <%= f.text_field(:customGenre, {:class => "form-control", placeholder: "Custom Genre", id: "customGenre"}) %>
</div>
```

show,html.erb (as of now)

```
    <h1>Genre(s)</h1>
    <%= @book.genres%>
```

Controller books_controller

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
def index  #step 4
    @books = Book.all
end

def show #step 3
    @book = Book.find(params[:id]) #get individual post page
end

def newBook 
    @book = Book.new
    #creates a new post of registered books 
    #<%=# f.check_box :genre, {:multiple => true}, id:"book_genre_#{i}"%>

end

def create #Step 2
    #render plain: params[:books].inspect #see what data is sent
    @book = Book.new(book_params)

    if(@book.save)
        redirect_to @book

    else
        render 'newBook' #if title is not there, just re renders newBook page
    end

end

def edit 
    @book = Book.find(params[:id]) #after this, make edit.html.erb
end

def update
    @book = Book.find(params[:id]) 

    if(@book.update(book_params))
        redirect_to @book
    else
        render 'edit'
    end

end

def destroy 

    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    @book.destroy

    redirect_to books_path
end

def mangaList
    @books = Book.all
end


private def book_params #can only be accessed from this class #step1 
    params.require(:books).permit(:title, :author, :description, :file, volumes: [], genres: [])
end
```

end

Book Model

```
 class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :file #upload file on book, create record in 
database 
    has_many_attached :volumes
    has_many :genres
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :author, presence: true
    validates_presence_of :description
    validates_presence_of :volumes
 end
```

Migration File

```
 class AddGenresToBook < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
   def change
     add_column :books, :genres, :string
   end
 end
```

Schema.db

```
 # This file is auto-generated from the current state of the 
 database. Instead
 # of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of 
 Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this 
schema definition.
```

# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source
    for your
   #database schema. If you need to create the application database on 
    another
    # system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the 
    migrations
    # from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach 
    (the more migrations
   # you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for 
   issues).
  #
   # It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your 
    version control system.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_08_29_130448) do

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.integer "record_id", null: false
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: 
  "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
     t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: 
  "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
   end

 create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "key", null: false
t.string "filename", null: false
t.string "content_type"
t.text "metadata"
t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
t.string "checksum", null: false
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: 
 true
   end
  # Could not dump table "books" because of following StandardError
  #   Unknown type '' for column 'description'

   create_table "genres", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: You will need a join table between `books` and `genres`. `has_many :genres` means that `genres` would have a `book_id` column but i am assuming that one book can have many genres and each genre can have_many books this is generally referred to as a has and belongs to many. Although I never use that relationship I much prefer has_many through on both sides.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Just to clarify, do you mean I would need a join table for my books controller and the genres attribute? 
Also, why would you prefer has_many through instead?